# How button with setOnClickListener() does unfinished job when other button is pressed?

Tags: android, button, kotlin

If I press button which is set to do job on click and I press other button immidiately while 1st button didn't finish his job, will 1st button finish his job or will be interupted in Kotlin?

Comment: First button must finish its job first .If the other button is in another thread .Both work parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the function of the 2nd button to affect the function of the 1st button, you can run these two operations/functions concurrently using [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html). It even applies best if the functions of both button 1 and 2 are long running tasks which would help ensure you don't block the `main thread`.

You set the functions of both button 1 and button 2 to run on separate `coroutines` while the `main thread` continues. These two functions will execute in the background while the `main thread` continues. You need to mark the functions of both button 1 and 2 as a `suspend` function which is a term to identify that a function is `coroutine` friendly.

Look up [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html) for better understanding.